# Mysql error "#1030 - Got error -1 from storage engine" when doing insert/update queries

Tags: mysql-5.5

I am starting to learn manipulating some long list of data from datalogs in mysql, around 300k entries, and it is being added by about 1k off entries everyday, it was working fine in a week then suddently I'm not able to write in the db. Here are the errors that I'm getting:

1. I can do select queries but when I do insert and update I am
   getting this error:

   > #1030 - Got error -1 from storage engine
2. When I try to change the engine type from InnoDB to MyISAM, I'm
   getting this error:

   > #1025 - Error on rename of './dbname/tablename'
   >   to './dbname/#sql2-500-37' (errno: -1
3. I can create new tables

These are the things that I have checked:

1. Any of my disk space is still more than 50%, I have checked it using df
2. Last line in the MySQL error log (/var/log/mysql/error.log):

   ```
   InnoDB: A new raw disk partition was initialized or
   InnoDB: innodb_force_recovery is on: we do not allow
   InnoDB: database modifications by the user. Shut down
   InnoDB: mysqld and edit my.cnf so that newraw is replaced
   InnoDB: with raw, and innodb_force_... is removed.
   ```
3. Tried restarting server & mysql service
4. I also tried doubling the values in the MySQL config file but it seems it doesn't help, here is my config file (`/etc/mysql/my.cnf`)

   ```
   [mysqld_safe]
   socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
   nice            = 0

   [mysqld]
   user            = mysql
   pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
   socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
   port            = 3306
   basedir         = /usr
   datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
   tmpdir          = /tmp
   lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
   skip-external-locking

   bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
   key_buffer              = 16M
   max_allowed_packet      = 16M
   thread_stack            = 192K
   thread_cache_size       = 8

   myisam-recover         = BACKUP
   #max_connections        = 100
   #table_cache            = 64
   #thread_concurrency     = 10
   #
   # * Query Cache Configuration
   #
   query_cache_limit       = 1M
   query_cache_size        = 16M


   expire_logs_days        = 10 .cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
   max_binlog_size         = 100M

   [mysqldump]
   quick
   quote-names
   max_allowed_packet      = 16M.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.


   [mysqldump]
   quick
   quote-names
   max_allowed_packet      = 16M

   [mysql]
   #no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

   [isamchk]
   key_buffer              = 16M

   !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
   innodb_force_recovery = 0
   ```

My server info is:

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
Protocol version: 10
User: sfere01@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

Any other tips on how to further troubleshoot & resolve this kind of issue? What other things should I have checked or missed?

Comment: Hi, I don't see the innodb_force_recovery option in your my.cnf file. If it is there, you should remove it.

Comment: @CraigEfrein I updated my post again to reflect my config, I added that when I was troubleshooting `innodb_force_recovery = 0`, and I removed it and it looks like it is working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will notice in the errors this message

> InnoDB: innodb_force_recovery is on: we do not allow InnoDB: database
>   modifications by the user. Shut down

So please remove the innodb_force_recovery option from my.cnf

Comment: Thanks Craig! it seems that was the culprit, we have inserted that to troubleshoot an earlier issue that we had

Comment: this can be found in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

Answer (score 5):

I had this error and my issue was resolved by doing the following:

Replace **ENGINE=MyISAM** with **ENGINE=InnoDB**

[Microsoft Reference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/06/08/azure-database-for-mysql-cant-restore-database-with-error-got-error-1-from-storage-engine/)

Comment: This worked! helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let the database decide which Engine to use, just remove **ENGINE=MyISAM** from the dump.